# What are valid characters in a Windows service (key) name?

Tags: windows, windows-services

Does anyone happen to know what the convention for Windows service key names is, which characters are legal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450(VS.85).aspx) for the underlying C++ structure used to create a service:

> The maximum string length is 256 characters. The service control manager database preserves the case of the characters, but service name comparisons are always case insensitive. Forward-slash (/) and backslash (\) are not valid service name characters.

Additionally, the following rules apply to the "Display Name":

> This string has a maximum length of 256 characters. The name is case-preserved in the service control manager. Display name comparisons are always case-insensitive.

Comment: Note: I have shown imperically that a `full stop` (**.**) is not valid either.

Comment: @soddoffBaldrick How exactly did you empirically validate that a full stop isn't valid? At least using the Win32 API it is a perfectly valid character in service names.

Answer (score 5):

Additional Information to the Response from Richard Szalay.

According to [ServiceInstaller.ServiceName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.servicename?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

> The ServiceName cannot be null or have zero length. ... It also cannot contain ... characters from the ASCII character set with value less than decimal value 32.